# QGIS doesn't recognize BETA2007.gsb for Transformation from GK3 to UTM

Tags: qgis, ntv2-transformation

I want to transform data from GK3 (EPSG:31467) to UTM(EPSG:25832) unsing the transformation grid BETA2007.gsb. BETA2007.gsb is already in the  **C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\share\proj** directory.
[image]

I should be able to select it as my default transformation method under **Settings->Options->CRS->Default Datum Transformations**. However, It doesn't appear as an option. It should be in the list shouldn't it?
[image]

Does anyone know how to add BETA2007.gsb into the list of default datum transformation methods? I tried it using version 3.10; 3.16 and 3.18. 1 year ago it worked under QGIS 4.X. It is strange that it doesn't work anymore or I'm doing sth. wrong now.